# Can the power supply be replaced on these powered audio speakers?

Tags: power-supply, voltage

I have 2 studio monitors (i.e., "speakers") and one subwoofer, all having 120v amplifiers built in. There is no voltage switch on them, and of course there are no "user serviceable parts". Is there a way to replace the power supplies with 240v units? The manufacturer says they will not do it for me, but they didn't say whether it is possible. Here are the manuals, which include circuit diagrams in the service manuals:

- [Monitor Owner's Manual](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzBFig3Q8-o6ZVlHalZjRm9FR1k/view?usp=sharing)
- [Monitor Service Manual](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzBFig3Q8-o6b1JmNjd5clcySGc/view?usp=sharing)
- [Subwoofer Owner's Manual](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzBFig3Q8-o6YXNOcUNIbTZYWWc/view?usp=sharing)
- [Subwoofer Service Manual](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzBFig3Q8-o6ek56ZmNBblVhTUU/view?usp=sharing)

According to the service manuals, there is a "power transformer" unit that is replaceable (separately from the circuit board it is mounted on), but the Yamaha parts department does not sell it separately. If I find a way to get the 240v transformer, how I can know whether it is safe to install it? Are consumer electronics generally built with a single unit that handles input power, such that the other electronic components are not dependent on factors like input voltage?

The alternative is to use an external step-down converter, but these are either unreliable or unreasonably expensive. They are also noisy, which is not great for a recording studio.

*Note: I'm not actually sure if this StackExchange site is the right place for this kind of question. If not, please tell me what you suggest. Thanks.*

**UPDATE**

The external converters are in fact the best solution for this. It requires doubling the capacity of the device, because the converters advertise a max wattage that is possible but not sustainable for more than about 20 minutes. So I got 3 separate converters, 2 @ 200W and 1 @ 500W. These work great, and they are silent (except for one that will hum if resting on one particular side).

The cost of the converters is a separate problem. Since I am using U.S. equipment in Europe, there is no market for the corresponding converters here, and hence the prices are exorbitant. So it's just a matter of looking elsewhere. Sellers on eBay often market worldwide and price according to the best markets, so I can get U.S. prices on U.S. converters with no extra charge for delivery to Europe. The only drawback: 45 days shipping from China! But they all got here, and they all work, so no big deal.

Comment: The cleanest solution is to sell the monitors and the sub, and buy new (used) ones for 240V. With a little bit of luck you might even break even. Added bonus if you're moving: You won't have to haul them across the border.

Comment: Selling equipment is an incredible amount of work, not to mention risky, and that the units are 10 years old (and they were floor models to begin with). Breaking even is certainly impossible.

Comment: Modifying the speakers is hardly going to let you break even either, but good luck, whatever route you elect to take.

Comment: The goal here is to change the transformers, not to save money. I don't want step-down converters in my studio, and I'm willing to pay extra to avoid them. So the question is, how exactly can these particular transformers be replaced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like the monitors are 100W each, and the subwoofer is 160W i.e. 360W total. 300W step-downs cost around £40 each on amazon, so if you bought 2 that would be £80 and cover everything you need.

Those manuals list different versions for different countries/voltages, so it's likely that the only difference is the input transformer that they use. If you could get a transformer from the same speaker for the uk region (wj271700 monitor and xw546a00 subwoofer) then it seems fairly easy to install it.

I googled and didnt find anything, maybe you could buy one from the manufacturer or buy a broken speaker and salvage it. Paying someone to install it + buying it will certainly cost >>£80.

Finding a compatible transformer will be difficult. Not only do these things have multiple different voltage outputs, this is an audio application - you'll always be wondering if the sound coming out of your £500-each speakers has been tainted by your mortal hands.

Comment: Agreed, though there are problems with step-down converters as well. First they are noisy, and second they are unreliable. In addition, the listed wattage is maximum capacity which in not sustainable, so for more than 30 minutes continuous usage the capacity is half what's listed. A reliable and quiet model would cost around $500 US.

Comment: well if you buy 3 (1 for each speaker), you'll sustain less (probably far less) than half their rated power levels. I've never used one, but I'm not sure what you mean about reliability. At this power, they're just a transformer, so I'm not really sure what there is that can fail. The only problem might be the noise, so maybe you could put it outside the room and just have extension cables. The bottom line is that unless you can find some of those yamaha transformers, this is the best way to do it.

Comment: People complain that their equipment does not work well on step-down converters, though I notice all the complaints are related to mechanical devices, whereas people with solid-state devices tend to be happy with the performance. As for noise, people complain that they "grind like a chainsaw", though perhaps those are just a few faulty units.

Comment: Well while you're looking for the replacement parts, for £40 you can buy this (https://www.amazon.co.uk/240v-120v-Step-Down-Transformer/dp/B000NIYH94) on prime to come on Saturday, try it, and if you don't like it, return for a full refund on Monday. The reviews seem pretty good, and there's really no risk.

Comment: C'est bon marché ça, ainsi que des bons avis. Mais c'est dommage que j'habite en France... Quand même, nous avons telles choses ici lesquelles je peux essayer. Anyway, so the lower-wattage units are more likely to work well? I was only considering a single unit for all 3 speakers, but maybe the stress on the transformer is not linear to capacity, which would make a 1000W unit much worse.

Comment: https://www.amazon.fr/Bronson-VT-300-Transformateur-Convertisseur/dp/B008ZZBSYO/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1508463682&sr=8-2&keywords=300w+110v will work just as well. The construction of the 1000W one will likely be a bit different, but there isnt really a way to tell if one would be better without trying them side by side. It may or may not be non-linear.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, i.e. it is possible. The specifics of which involve much knowledge of the details of the internal workings than you have. Why not just use a 240v to 120v adapter?

Comment: It requires a step-down converter capable of 1000 watts. Retail models are noisy, unreliable and expensive. If there's a way to swap the PSU, or pay someone to do it, that would probably work out much better.